# Backend services isolation in Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

We are planning using Zuul in production as an API gateway. I am not sure the behavior of Zuul in this specific scenario.

Suppose there are two back-end services A and B sitting behind Zuul. Service A is a slow one but with a lot of traffic. What will happen to the clients visiting Service B through Zuul?

On the clients' side, Service B will be unavailable because Service A slow down the Zuul so there is no resource to handle the request for Service B.
I'm not sure about this, and any advice or experience will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the individual endpoints to use their own thread pools and have their own timeouts.

```
zuul:
    ribbonIsolationStrategy: THREAD
    threadPool:
        useSeparateThreadPools: true
host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
routes:
    examples2:
      path: /something/**
      serviceId: examples
      stripPrefix: true
    services:
      path: /services/**
      serviceId: services
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders: true
    auth:
      path: /oauth/**
      serviceId: saapi-auth-server
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders: true

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

auth:
  ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 60000
    ConnectTimeout: 60000

services:
  ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 60000
    ConnectTimeout: 60000
```

Here is an example config from one of our gateways that should get you started.

Comment: we are using URL not serviceid，but I think I can use static URL in ribbon.